# For Loop, why index out of range?

Tags: python, indexoutofrangeexception

Write a function named `same_values()` that takes two lists of numbers of equal size as parameters.
The function should return a list of the indices where the values were equal in `lst1` and `lst2`.
For example, the following code should return

```
[0, 2, 3]

same_values([5, 1, -10, 3, 3], [5, 10, -10, 3, 5])
```

My original attempt:

```
def same_values(lst1, lst2):
  new_list=[]
  for i in lst1:
    for j in lst2:
      if lst1[i] == lst2[j]:
        new_list.append(lst1[i])
  return new_list
```

I looked up the solution which is:

```
def same_values(lst1, lst2):
  new_lst = []
  for index in range(len(lst1)):
    if lst1[index] == lst2[index]:
      new_lst.append(index)
  return new_lst
```

yet I wonder why my original attempt is not valid (it says list index out of range which I don't get in this case). Thanks everyone for helping me out!

Comment: Aren't you getting the values from the first list, and then looking at the index of the second list with that value?

Comment: You're using for-each type of loop - for each *element* in the list. That means your `i` is not element's index but the element itself. Try adding printing i and j in the middle of the loop and see for yourself

Comment: BTW I believe the best solution is: `def same_values(lst1, lst2): return [ i for (i, (v1, v2)) in enumerate(zip(lst1, lst2)) if v1==v2 ]`

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
lst1 = [5, 1, -10, 3, 3]
for i in lst1:
    print(i)
```

You are actually iterating over the values in the list, not the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

In the below condition  i is considered as array value. so i would be 5,1,-1, which are invalid indexes

```
def same_values(lst1, lst2):
  new_list=[]
  for i in lst1:
    for j in lst2:
      if lst1[i] == lst2[j]:
        new_list.append(lst1[i])
  return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 major issues (i.e. go against the problem statement) with your logic:

1. You are comparing every value in list 1 to every value in list 2. So, if you the following lists [10,1,10,1,10] and [1,10,1,10,1] your code would identify all 5 position as positive hits
2. Instead of recording the index or position where you get the a positive hit, you are recording the corresponding value from list 1. In your example, instead of [0,2,3] you would get [5,-10,3]

That being said, have you actually tried running your code? It would be very helpful to you if you actually debugged your code and stepped through each operation.